# A continue directive with label to break inner loop and iterate outer loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am trying to get a handle on continue/break labels in inner loops.

My code below attempts to output all the prime numbers up to the `userNumber`.

My test for whether the numbers up to the `userNumber` are prime numbers involves an outer loop incrementing `i` starting from 1 to the userNumber, and then using an inner loop dividing `i` by `j` with `j` incremented in a loop to test for a remainder (the presence of one meaning it'd be a prime).

I made it so that in the inner loop if `i % j === 0` that `i` will `continue outerLoop` to the next outer loop iteration, but for some reason, when I test and input `userNumber` as any non-prime number, no output is given, but then an input of a prime number seemingly results as intended.

The inner loop upon seeing a non-prime, should find there being no remainder, and continue the next iteration of `outerLoop`, but that's not the case. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
 const userNumber = +prompt('Insert number, please');
           let prime = 'These are the primes under your number: ';
           
           outerLoop: 
           for (let i = 1; i <= userNumber; i++) {
                if (i === 1 || i === 2 || i === 3) {
                    prime += `${i} `;
                    continue;
                }    
            
                for (let j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                    if (j === 1) 
                    continue;
                   
                    if ( i % j === 0) continue outerLoop;
                           
                } 
            
                prime += `${i} `;
            }
```

Comment: I do not understand 'no output is given' If I run your code exactly as it is with an alert(prime) at the end I see all the prime numbers up to an even number (have tested it on several up to 60). Could you make your code into a runnable snippet and test that it does indeed show the problem?

Comment: @AHaworth I apologize. I asked for help in a discord and realized that I was looking to print `prime` but write code to do that. I thought by just have `prime` it would print the script assigned to `prime` in my console. I had a huge brain fart and I keep forgetting I have to console.log(). Thank you for trying to help!! I would close this message, but don't have the ability to do so, yet.